# Running 1000 permutation tests in R for correlation

Tags: r, resampling

I would like to run 1000 permutation tests on the "law" dataset in R to test for the significance of the correlation between LSAT scores and GPA. I have the following code:

```
nperm <- 1000
law.perm <- rep(0,nperm)
for (i in 1:nperm) {
   ind <- sample(law)
   law <- ind
   Group1 <- law$LSAT[law==1]
   Group2 <- law$GPA[law==2]
   law.perm[i] <- cor(Group1,Group2)
}
law.perm
```

However, running the above code produces all NA values for the correlations. Could anyone help identify the issue?

Here's some sample output:

```
str(law)
'data.frame':   15 obs. of  2 variables:
$ LSAT: num  576 635 558 578 666 580 555 661 651 605 ...
$ GPA : num  3.39 3.3 2.81 3.03 3.44 3.07 3 3.43 3.36 3.13 ...
```

Comment: What is `law` before the first `sample`? After `law <- ind` the subsetting `law$LSAT[law==1]` doesn't make sense. Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(law)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(law, 20))`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas I actually don't know what `law==1` means, an example from class has the same kind of format so I'm using it here. I guess it's a way to permute the two groups? I've also edited my question to show what the data look like. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dataset `law` is in package `bootstrap`. And what you are doing seems to be a non-parametric bootstrap. here are two different ways, with a `for` loop and with function `bootstrap::bootstrap`.

Before running the code, load the dataset.

```
library(bootstrap)

data(law)
```

First, the way you are trying in the question, corrected.

```
set.seed(1234)    # Make the results reproducible

nperm <- 1000
law.perm <- numeric(nperm)
n <- nrow(law)
for (i in 1:nperm) {
  ind <- sample(n, replace = TRUE)
  law.perm[i] <- cor(law[ind, "LSAT"], law[ind, "GPA"])
}
```

Second way, using the `bootstrap` function. This follows the last example in the function's help page.

```
theta <- function(x, xdata){ 
  cor(xdata[x, 1], xdata[x, 2]) 
}

set.seed(1234)
res <- bootstrap(seq_len(n), nperm, theta = theta, law)
```

Compare both results.

```
mean(law.perm)
#[1] 0.769645

mean(res$thetastar)
#[1] 0.7702782
```

The difference in the medians is smaller.

```
median(law.perm)
#[1] 0.7938093

median(res$thetastar)
#[1] 0.7911014
```

And graph both results.

```
op <- par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
hist(law.perm, prob = TRUE)
hist(res$thetastar, prob = TRUE)
par(op)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! I just have a quick question about the permutation test code. Since Permutation tests are done without replacement, shouldn't `replace = FALSE`? Also, I just to graph a histogram of the permutation tests using `hist(law.perm, xlab = "Correlation", main = "Histogram of Correlation from 1000 Permutations")` and `abline(v=correlation,col='blue',lwd=2)` but it shows the true correlation is close to 0.

Comment: Oh never mind, I just restarted the RStudio and now it shows an updated histogram. Thanks!

Comment: @JinYuLi As for the `replace = FALSE`, you are right, I was thinking of the bootstrap code, I will correct that point.

Comment: @JinYuLi Sorry, correction to what I said in my comment above. If you shuffle both vectors by the same `ind` the correlations will be exactly the same, there is no point in doing that.